# How can I tell if I have the bootcamp windows drivers installed

Tags: bootcamp, windows

What things should I look for in Windows to determine whether I have the bootcamp drivers installed? Are there some files or registry settings I can check for?

Comment: My concern has to do with installing Windows on older model Mac computers. Sometimes Windows will be installed to incorrectly use a EFI boot method, instead of the legacy BIOS boot method. In these cases, some  hardware may not work correctly even after installing the Boot Camp drivers. I only mention this in case you fall into this category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways

1. Look for the Boot Camp icon in the system tray. It's a gray diamond and when you hover your mouse over it it says Boot Camp
2. Open Control Panel, there should be a Boot Camp icon
3. Open device manager, there should be several devices listed that show up as "Apple [name of device]"

Also note that if you have one or more unknown devices (they'll have little yellow triangles on them in Device Manager) it could be that one or more Apple drivers are not installed, and/or damaged and need to be reinstalled. Run Apple Software Update from the start menu and it should find updated Boot Camp drivers.

Answer (score 0):

The ‘Boot Camp drivers’ are two main things: Boot Camp Control Panel (for adjusting Mac-relevant Boot Camp settings) and drivers for hardware components. This is why Boot Camp refers to the ‘drivers’ as ‘support files’ because there's a little more than just drivers for Windows.

Windows 10 can automatically install a few of these hardware drivers, such as Bluetooth or Wi-Fi without the need to run their installers provided by Boot Camp (occasionally even newer versions are available outside of the Boot Camp drivers). Whilst these drivers are installed as part of the Boot Camp support files, identifying whether they are part of the Boot Camp drivers is an effort in futility.

The Boot Camp control panel can be found in the notification area if running, or in the Start Menu or Program Files folder. You can see if the software is installed in Programs and Features in Windows.

Without knowing why it's useful for you to know whether Boot Camp is installed, it's not really possible to say where to look, as there are too many independent components which make up the Boot Camp Windows support software.

Answer (score 0):

The command below will list of 3rd party drivers in the Windows drivers store.

```
dism  /online  /get-drivers  /format:table
```

Amongst these drivers are the Apple's Windows Support Software drivers. It is possible that all the drivers listed are from the Windows Support Software.

If you want all the drivers, including those which came with Windows, then use this command.

```
dism  /online  /get-drivers  /format:table  /all
```

> Note: Just because a driver is in the store, does not mean Windows is using the driver.

You can determine exactly which drivers are part of the Windows Support Software by comparing the following lists which can be made during the installation of Windows.

- Listing third party drivers in the Windows image.
- Listing third party drivers from `$WinPEDriver$` folder as they are added to the store.
- Listing the third party drivers before running the `setup` application in the `BootCamp` folder.
- Listing the third party drivers after running the `setup` application in the `BootCamp` folder.

Your Mac probably should not be connected to the internet while making these lists.